# jQuery ready, doesn't show elements loaded through ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm trying to create a more generic local-storage setup for my application so I don't have to create a function for each time I add a new element to the page that I want to store in local storage. I have my jquery setup like so.

```
/* SET LOCAL STORAGE */
    $( document ).on( "keyup",".localStorage",function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if(id) {
            id = "#" + id;
            localStorage.setItem(id, $(this).val());
        }
    });
```

The part that seems to be having some difficulty, is when the page is loaded, looping through each "*.localStorage*" element and applying the proper data (somewhat like saving as a draft).

I can't seem to use jQuery's $each() function, as that doesn't work with elements loaded through $ajax().

So what's the best way to find elements on a page even if they are loaded dynamically? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: sounds like you try to access the elements before they exist. It is like trying to eat a pizza before the delivery guy drops it off. You need to listen for the Ajax calls to end and than set it.

Comment: Yeah, just not sure the best way to go about waiting for them to populate the page. IE, dynamic tabs on a page, and you change the tab, the content loads through ajax. You need to run a callback or something I would assume. Just not sure the best approach in general.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN in fact access elements added dynamically to the page. I would just try something like this in your event code:

```
var elements = $('.localstorage');
for (var i in elements) {
   doStuf(elements[i]);
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't get elements loaded in dynamically. IE(tabs that load from a dynamic url)

Comment: you can't access other browser tabs from javascript. you should have mentioned that in your question.

Comment: Sorry, no, jquery ui -tabs. if the data inside that tab is loaded via dynamic URL (locally) it doesn't work. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it makes sense. the content isn't there yet. you'll need to populate that data somewhere and modify it.